# Position of overlay on orientation change in jQuery mobile

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm working on jQuery mobile. I have an overlay which pops out on tap of a button in the header. The overlay appears close to the button.

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a" data-tap-toggle="false">
<h1>Photos</h1>
    <a href="#photomenu" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="notext"
   data-rel="popup" data-transition="slidedown"></a>
 </div>
```

But on orientation change the overlay appears at the center.
How to retain the position of the overlay on orientation change? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

By default, popups open centered vertically and horizontally over the thing you clicked (the origin) which is good for popups used as tooltips or menus. The framework also applies some basic collision detection rules to ensure that the popup will appear on-screen so the ultimate position may not always be centered over the origin.

For situations like a dialog or lightbox where the popup should appear centered within the window instead of over the origin, add the data-position-to attribute to the link and specify a value of window.

It's also possible to specify any valid selector as the value of position-to in addition to origin and window. For example, if you add data-position-to="#myElement" the popup will be positioned over the element with the id myElement.

```
<a href="#positionWindow" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window">Position to window</a>

<div data-role="popup" id="positionWindow">
    <p>I am positioned to the window.</p>
</div>
```

I have also made you a live jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/8xCYB/

Comment: Thanks for your response. But i do not want the overlay to be positioned at the center. It should appear next to the button. If I use data-position-to="origin" , the overlay appears next to the button but on orientation change the overlay again appears at the center of the window.

Comment: What mobile platform are you using and what version? I have tested it on android 4.1 and it works just fine.